# How do the web protection products which intercept SSL traffic using proxy, work with sites implementing SSL pinning?

Tags: security, networking, https, pinning

How do the web protection products which intercept SSL traffic using proxy, work with sites implementing SSL pinning?

Examples of web protection products which intercept SSL traffic -
Blue Coat Proxy SG 
Sophos Gateway
McAfee Web Gateway

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. It could be on-topic in http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Public_Key_Pinning :

> Firefox and Chrome disable Pin Validation for Pinned Hosts whose
>   validated certificate chain terminates at a user-defined trust anchor
>   (rather than a built-in trust anchor). This means that for users who
>   imported custom root certificates all pinning violations are ignored.

In other words, for that kind of interception, SSL pinning is disabled, because the user agree to the interception (by installing a software / a certificate)